# Turning normal image into a sketched looking image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to know if there is an easy way to turn a normal looking icon into one that looked sketched. I need some or a web project I am working on, ill give an example.

Normal image:
[image]

Sketched looking:
[image]

Now I want to do this for some icons that are not available, such as the android logo:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the example which you are showing is way different from what i made,
all you have to do is recreate all of your icon the way i did till any one suggest something ;), its quite difficult to get the same output as you want(Gmail icon)  with the help of Photoshop....

first of all go to filters and add some noise and follow SS.

[image]

If you can use adobe Illustrator

- [how to sketch icon illustrator](http://www.doublejdesign.co.uk/2009/03/how-to-draw-sketch-style-icons-in-illustrator/)

Hope this will help....

Comment: Wow this looks actually pretty good, I am going to try this with a few different icons, see how the results are. I think this is the best that can be done. Awesome!!

Comment: A useful preliminary step would be to run Filter > Distort > Ripple, with the "Small" setting. Give yourself a little bit of extra canvas to allow the edges to roughen up. For extra credit, instead of Ripple, build a displacement map you can use for all of your icons. Use Filter > Distort > Displace on each icon before you run the steps Jack has given. (See Photoshop Help for details of how to set up a displacement map.)

Comment: cool man. really great example! Appreciate all the screenshots too

Answer (score 3):

In CS5, at least: Filters→Sketch→Graphic Pen, go to town.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this, but it turns it black and white.

Comment: throw a Layer on it and recolor it?

Comment: I like "go to town" -- A quick pit-stop at Starbucks, then off to the movies? :-)

Comment: can it be a local coffee shop? Starbucks is undrinkable sludge without the candy-bar-in-a-cup toppings they drown it with.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the easiest solution is to print out the image, place it under some tracing paper and then grab a pencil.

Comment: … a pencil, or, a graphic tablet! Would be able to skip the scanning and then the retracing.

Comment: Yes I am considering buying this. Do you maybe have some information on what is a good graphic tablet to consider buying. I mean one that is good for basic stuff, but for a reasonable price.